# ASP.NET C# [createnew] property attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

while reading this tutorial at 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380215/Understanding-MVP-WCSF-Over-ASP-NET-Web-Forms?msg=4970179#xx4970179xx
I find the attribute [CreateNew] used with property Presenter

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this._presenter.OnViewInitialized();
    }
    this._presenter.OnViewLoaded();
}


[CreateNew]
public ProductPresenter Presenter
{
    get
    {
        return this._presenter;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        this._presenter = value;
        this._presenter.View = this;
    }
}
```

and here it is used before method parameter

```
private IProductsController _controller;

public ProductPresenter([CreateNew] IProductsController controller)
{
    //// Method on controller class invoked here
    _controller = controller;
}
```

What does the attribute [CreateNew] meand before property and what does it mean when used with the method parameter? Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.objectbuilder.createnewattribute.aspx.  You can Google such things as "CreateNewAttribute C#"

Comment: Many thanks, it still does not tell me how it affects property or method?

Comment: [Working with ObjectBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699209.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Here it is. [CreateNew] is used to create new object for dependency
 injection
[Dependency Injection and the Composite Application Block (Introduction to CAB/SCSF Part 5)](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/08/05/dependency-injection-and-the-composite-application-block-introduction-to-cabscsf-part-5/)

It is part of the Composite Application Block and here is a good in fact a very good tutorial introducing the Composite Application Block and Smart Client Software Factory - Introduction to CAB/SCSF.
And here is the link for tutorial table of contents for all tutorial parts
[Table of Contents: Introduction to CAB/SCSF](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/intro-to-cab-toc/)